# manipulating character strings communicated over Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, external-keyboard

I successfully installed a Bluetooth Keyboard Emulator for an Android device – it has keyboard and mouse control that works nicely.
I wonder if there is a way to “break” the app to get access to the character strings that are communicated from the Android device to the notebook, via the Bluetooth link, to support manipulation or feeding “synthetic” character strings to the notebook.

Comment: That depends how the app is implements. Unfortunately you don't name the app (inclusive [Play Store] link) so everything we say can be true or false.

Comment: The link to the product: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.appground.blek&hl=en_US&gl=US

Comment: Have you checked the forum the app details mentions if you post your feature wish there? Changing an app e.g. via `apktool` requires detailed knowledge about Android and it's Java API as well as Smali language as decompilation to Java is usually not an option if you want to modify something.